# Responsive Design Div Spacing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, margin

I've got a problem with div spacing in responsive design if you go to this url: http://www.false-idolz.com/mobile.html you'll se how when you decrease to the maximum de window width the div spacing gets bigger instead of smaller... why does it happen? how do i fix it? Thanks!

```
<table>
<div>
<tr>
<td>
......texto.........
</td>
</tr>
</div>
<div>
<tr>
<td>
......texto.........
</td>
</tr>
</div>
</table>
```

This is the example of the code I am using everything works but spacing

Comment: Inspecting the source code reveals that you have got tables within tables - not only is this bad practice, but it will also cause many problems and I suspect that this is one of them. 

Honestly, I think there is far too much for us to change in order to get your code working as intended. Please redesign your layout, without using tables within tables, then we if you still have difficulty come back to us.

Comment: Thanks for answering ! I'm going to clean all up and see if it works!

Comment: Solved ! This was the problem... !

Comment: Okay, I'll move this to an answer and then we can delete these comments. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Transferred from comments as this proved to be the answer**

Inspecting the source code reveals that you have got tables within tables - not only is this bad practice, but it will also cause many problems and I suspect that this is one of them. <s>Honestly, I think there is far too much for us to change in order to get your code working as intended.</s> Please redesign your layout, without using tables within tables, <s>then we if you still have difficulty come back to us.</s>